# writing unit tests for rails app, which consider testing the app daemons too

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, daemons, railsapps, ruby-daemons

I've got a Rails app that incorporates some daemons. Unfortunately, I haven't written unit tests for the app yet. I've recently decided to rectify that, but I'm facing a challenge—I can't figure out a way to simulate daemons effectively during test runs. Any advice or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Generally you want to stub out any daemons or external services in your tests.

Comment: Simply test your "internals," such as the library (or service, if you prefer) layer. The daemon part can be written once, tested manually, and later not touched. If touched for some reason, manually re-test.